# How to design the user/order/shipping model in mongo for a e-commerce app?

Tags: database, mongodb, e-commerce

Every order has a shipping info and every user has several shipping addresses. This is my design:

```
User:
   ...
   defaultAddress: ObjectId
   ...
```

```
Address:
   ...
   ...   
   ...
```

```
Order:
   ...
   shipping: ObjectId  
   ...
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is it reasonable to use a reference for shipping in Order Model, or just embed the entire Address object.
2. Every time add a new address from App, Is there any better way to check if it is already exist in mongodb?
3. Should I keep a defaultAddress key in User Model, or should I just use a array to keep all the address object?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Addresses bind closely to Users, so make Addresses an array inside Users.

Depending on your overall audit / revisioning data architecture, you *may* wish to copy the address into the Order doc upon creation to create an unambiguous record of where it went.  Having Order reference back into User and address implies you cannot change the address; you would have to mark it as no longer active *but not deleted*.
Note you do not have to laborious copy all the fields; you can treat the selected address as an object, something like:

```js
var addr = get addr;  // from DB or wherever; any shape with any number of subfields is fine.                                 

db.order.insert({orderId:"someID", date:new ISODate(), shippingAddress: addr});
```

To prevent dupes, it is a matter of looking up the info in the array -- but of course caveats apply such as making sure you canonicalize case, strip white space, remove unnecessary punctuation, etc. etc.   Let's assume you have `street`,`city`, and `state` as the matchable fields:

```js
{
    "user":"U1",
    "addrs": [
        {street: "20 Pine Ln", city: "Smallville", state: 'NM'},
        {street: "16 Elm Ln", city: "Denver", state: 'CO'},
        {street: "77 Sunshine Pkway", city: "Denver", state: 'CO'},
    ]
}
```

After grooming the input from app, assume we have a target lookup doc like this.  Note: We do **NOT** have to create the doc with fields in a particular order.

```js
var target = {city: "Denver", state: 'CO', street: '16 Elm Ln'};
```

The lookup is simple.  Since `addrs` is an array, the match will dive into and iterate over the array.  The `$elemMatch` operator ensures that ALL fields in the candidate match those in the target.

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$match: {user:'U1', "addrs":{$elemMatch: target} }}
]);
```

If no records are found, then this is a new address.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For the first issue, I have another two questions: 1. An address object may have 7 or more properties, if there are thousands of duplicate addresses in order model, will it cause any performance issue? It sounds very redundancy. Another question is, you mentioned we should created an unambiguous record, what about the product info? It may be much complicated than the address info, it sounds unreasonable if we keep all the product info as an object data.

Comment: For the second issue, the address object also includes the name and tel as well, so this match may not enough for the lookup, it seems every property in address object should be checked.

Comment: @jw.h  I suspect it will actually be a performance boost, at the expense of increased storage, but with a much simpler audit/versioning trail.   If you want to always be able to tie an order back to an address, then the address can never change after it is used.   This is OK; you just have to build live/retired status into each address and give each one a terse unique ID (only has to be unique within user, so 2 chars is probably enough, smaller than an int).   Same concept applies to product.  If you copy a ref, you can never remove it.

Comment: For second issue, the match is completely up to you.  This is not a single scalar value-to-value match; this is business interpretation of address equality.   For example, what if 2 addresses are same except zipcode?   Are they different -- or is it a mistake?  The number of fields and logic is not a DB function.

Comment: Yes, actually I'm going to keep all the record in db instead of deleting them. This is not a big cost. The only cost is a query operation while reading the order data. For my point of view, this design seems more reasonable, but I don't understand why most e-commerce database is designed the way you mentioned, which is to embed all the shipping object inside a order.

Comment: For the second one, What I am wondering is if there is another way to do the query instead of comparing all the properties. For example, can we use a hash value as the object ID. Every time we get a address object, we make it to a hash value and use this hash value for all the db operations. Is that necessary?